# How to write a NFC message without overwriting an existing message on the tag

Tags: android, nfc

I am developing an app using NFC technology and I am a newbie in Android development.

I want to write a tag without overwriting an existing tag. I have done with the app but when I write something the previously added tag gets overwritten.

Is there any way to append records in a nfc tag.

Following is the code used in the app.

```
private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
    // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    // Enable I/O
    ndef.connect();
    // Write the message
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    // Close the connection
    ndef.close();
}



private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang       = "en";
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength = langBytes.length;
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}
```

I've found this question [Can NFC tags be protected from being overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669833/can-nfc-tags-be-protected-from-being-over-written) but it is about to make a tag read-only which means to write a tag permanently which i don't want.

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Comment: Please do look at the code.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25169226/1276636) work for you?

Comment: yes but overwriting the existing tag. I want to add the new record by keeping the existing one.

Comment: Have you had any success with Googling? How about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669833/can-nfc-tags-be-protected-from-being-over-written)?

Comment: will making a tag read-only make it not deletable or overwritten ....?

Comment: Have you tried both linked answers?

Comment: yes sir, i have tried both of them.

Comment: To make a tag read-only is an irreversible process and i dont want to write a tag permanently.

Comment: I was expecting you'd tell if it worked or not, and if it didn't then what you found out, etc. :)

Comment: Not yet found anything that matches the requirement :'(

Comment: "i dont want to write a tag permanently." Then I believe it is not possible. You could update your question to contain what you've found out. This will increase your chances of getting a helpful response.

Answer (score 2):

You could write multiple [`NdefRecord`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html)s in a [`NdefMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html).
So you could check if current tag have `NdefRecord` if yes you add your `NdefRecord` and then write `NdefMessage` with old and new records.

There's multiple threads talking about this:

- [Android Read/Write to Multiple Records NDEF NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633383/android-read-write-to-multiple-records-ndef-nfc)
- [Writing multiple data types in NFC tags in a single tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927642/writing-multiple-data-types-in-nfc-tags-in-a-single-tap)
- [Android app to add mutiple record in NFC tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427997/android-app-to-add-mutiple-record-in-nfc-tag)

Comment: @SwapnilLanjewar Is it useful ?